# Login via different port Angular Spring

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, spring-security

I've aldready created login functionality that works on localhost:8080 using spring security and jsp file. Everyting is fine with it.

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticateTheUser"
                           method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

                    <!-- User name -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>

                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" >
                    </div>

                    <!-- Login/Submit Button -->
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 150px; margin: 0 auto">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--tokens-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

                </form:form>
```

I've created new angular project that works on port 4200 and I want to use my spring backend to login via angular. I've tried something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/authenticateTheUser" method="post">
  <!-- User name -->
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <!-- Password -->
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>

    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" >
  </div>

  <!-- Login/Submit Button -->
  <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 150px; margin: 0 auto">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to combine my angular project with spring backend?

Answer (score 0):

Use the proxy server that is built in to the Angular CLI. 
See the documentation at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: This solution doesn't handle my problem. I'm able to send requests to the other server (e. g. get data from backend), but my only problem is login on that server and make angular know that I'm logged or not.